# SerializationUtils not present in fabric 6.*

Tags: fabric8, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am using the following lines using fabric client

```
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SerializationUtils;
String actualYaml = SerializationUtils.dumpAsYaml(job);
```

This was working in fabric version `5.*`, but when I moved to later version like `io.fabric8:kubernetes-client:6.6.2`, this `SerializationUtils` is not found. I believe this is deprecated.

Is there any alternate for this? How do I achieve the same functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Serialization](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/v6.6.2/kubernetes-client-api/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/utils/Serialization.java)

In order to serialize as JSON string use:

```java
String actualJson = Serialization.asJson(job);
```

In order to serialize as YAML string use:

```java
String actualYaml = Serialization.asYaml(job);
```